# Catch server timeout on calling xml

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ipad, timeout, nsxmlparser

```
[[NSXMLParser alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:@"www.mysite.com/myXml.mxl"];
```

to get xml and after that i use parser funcions.

Now, if the server is down? or **responding too slow**, is there a way to **set / get server timeout** response **in NSXMLParser** ??

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend using something like [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) or [NSURLConnection](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSURLConnection_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to pull your data. They provide more control over this sort of thing. These libraries support advanced features like timeouts and ASI even includes the ability to track progress of a download. Very useful for giving your app that touch of usability flow.

You can pull an NSData out of them, then pass it to the NSXMLParser with `[[NSXML Parser alloc] initWithContentsOfData: data];`.

If you have any more questions, just comment :)

Good luck,

Aurum Aquila

Comment: you say if I create a http wrapper and passed to the parser nsdata? it's correct? nsurlconnection could detect timeout, right?

Comment: `NSURLConnection` does not allow you to set a timeout, but it does do error handling. Check out the docs I linked. The nice thing about `ASIHTTPRequest` is that you can set a custom timeout. If the request takes longer than the allotted time, it'll throw an error. It all really depends on what you're doing. `NSURLConnection` is convenient, but not as powerful. ASI is a bit of a nightmare to set up, but provides high-precision control.